# Coupling object hierarchy and operations

Tags: design-patterns

As part of a parser library, I have the following object hierarchy:

```
             ParseEntry
                 |
                 |
                / \
               /   \
              /     \
NumericParseEntry   StringParseEntry
```

etc.,

These objects basically hold data. Then, I have a set of operations like evaluate (to evaluate if a value passes the parse entry criterion), generateSQL (to generate a SQL condition based on the parse entry criterion).

Owing to the Single Responsibility Principle, I don't want to add these functions to the specific parse entry classes and want to maintain separate hierarchies that implement these functions for the parse entry hierarchy. This allows me to reuse a certain implementation for more than one parse entry.

I was wondering how to couple the operations with the objects such that while I am browsing through a parse table of parse entries performing some operation, I should be able to get the appropriate operation object.

One crude way I could think about is to have a factory class that maintains a map between the parse entry type and its corresponding evaluator/SQLgenerator. Another way is to embed the evaluator/sql generator as data members of parse entry and return them in getters.

Any help to improvise on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain data objects aren't very object-oriented. I would argue that the operations (evaluate / generateSQL) are indeed the responsibility of the `ParseEntry` objects. If you want to reuse the evaluator implementation, you could still compose an `Evaluator` in `ParseEntry` and delegate to it, for example:

```
public class NumericParseEntry extends ParseEntry {
  private Evaluator evaluator = ...;
  private SQLGenerator sqlGenerator = ...;

  public bool evaluate(Object value) {
    return evaluator.evaluate(this, value);
  }

  public String generateSQL() {
    return sqlGenerator.generateSQL(this);
  }
}
```

The Single Responsibility Principle says there should only be one reason for a class to change -- and if your change is indeed related to a specific `ParseEntry`, there is nothing wrong in changing the class.

---

Also, you could consider using inheritance and getting rid of the separate `Evaluator` / `Generator` classes altogether. For example:

```
public class NumericParseEntry extends ParseEntry {
  // put common logic for numeric entries here
}

public class IntegerParseEntry extends NumericParseEntry {
  // put specialized code for handling integers
}

public class FloatParseEntry extends NumericParseEntry {
  // put specialized code for handling floating-point
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I agree with argument that these operations should essentially be implemented in the specific parse entry classes. I like your idea to move the evaluation code to a separate hierarchy and include them in parse entry through composition.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) to me. You would have `EvaluatorVisitor` and `SQLGenerationVisitor` which will have *visit* operations on `ParseEntry`s. `ParseEntry` is an *Element* containing an `accept(Visitor)` operation which `NumericParseEntry` and `StringParseEntry` would extend.

Because you are using the Visitor pattern, Single Responsibility principle comes for free.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I too agree that the operations could be visitors, conceptually. But I am facing issues implementing it in Java using Generics with the signature of accept method in the parse entry interface to have strong typing between what evaluator works on what parse entry.

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully used this pattern [Implementing Complex Case Analysis](http://blogs.southworks.net/dgeffner/2011/09/26/implementing-complex-case-analysis/) to implement similar things to what you are trying to do... You'll be able to create code dependent on the type or on whatever conditions you choose, in an elegant way, without modifying the "data" hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Though I am not personally inclined to use a framework to solve my problem, this is a good reference I came to know through you which might be helpful in future. thanks again!